# how to use regex for finding numbers with comma after a specific string in python?

Tags: python, regex

how to find numbers with comma after certain string using regex python3?

```
import re
word = re.search(r'sum RM (\d+) \d+(?:,\d+)?', 'sum RM 320,000.00')
print(word)


 Expected:
 RM 320,000.00
```

Comment: Try the accepted answer on the string `sum RM ,,,` it will give you `RM ,,,` even if there is no number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import re
word = re.findall(r'sum (RM [0-9,.]*)', 'sum RM 320,000.00')
print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` returns match groups which you need to capture:

```
import re

word = re.search(r'sum (RM \d+(?:,\d+)(?:.\d+)?)', 'sum RM 320,000.00')
print(word.group(1))

# RM 320,000.00
```

Comment: Better but if the OP does really want to accept well formed comma separated numbers than this regex is not correct, also if you use `\d` you accept all unicode numbers including hindi, japanese,... numbers. Anyway +1! Even if OP chose the worst possible answer lol

Comment: @Allan, better yet; a well explained answer from you. +1 to you as well (should've been the accepted one).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not only want to match numbers with `,` in it but if those numbers must respect the standard of adding a comma after every 3 digits for reading purpose, then use the regex:

```
r'sum (RM [0-9]{1,3}(:?,[0-9]{3})+(:?\.[0-9]+)?)'
```

Explanations:

- `[0-9]{1,3}` 1 to 3 digits in the range `[0-9]` if you use `\d` you will also accept unicode digits like: 1１2２3３
- `(:?,[0-9]{3})+` comma followed by some group of 3 ascii digits repeated 1 to N times with N being an int > 1
- `(:?\.[0-9]+)?` eventually some decimal part

**code:**

```
import re

#to match only numbers with comma every 3 digits
regex = r'sum (RM [0-9]{1,3}(:?,[0-9]{3})+(:?\.[0-9]+)?)'

print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 320,000.00').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 320,000.00') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM ,,,').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM ,,,') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 3,00').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 3,00') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 3123,000').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 3123,000') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 31,000').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 31,000') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 312,000').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 312,000') else None)
print(re.search(regex, 'sum RM 312,00').group(1) if re.search(regex, 'sum RM 312,00') else None)
```

**output:**

```
RM 320,000.00
None
None
None
RM 31,000
RM 312,000
None
```